# Enterprise Library or Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enterprise-library

which one is more useful for a project with a huge database

useful means :

1. Insert and delete and update fast
2. select a lot of rows fast
3. update database structure easier
4. programmer friendly
5. , .....

we have considered that database implement is in the best situation of indexing and ....

thanks

Comment: I hate the way questions get shutdown and closed on SO as 'opinion based'. It's fairly obvious to anyone with half a brain that the poster is after opinions, and personal stories from people who have used one or both approaches. They have even provided some suggested ways of comparing them - all of which are valid IMO. You wouldn't use both on a project, so why might you choose one over the other? I suspect the accepted answer doesn't help at all, at it simply says they are different, and for that reason can't be compared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://forums.asp.net/t/1647988.aspx:

DAAB is the Data Access Block provided by Ent. Lib.

> They are completely different animals. The DAAB is a data access library (wrappers around  ADO.NET), whereas the Entity Framework is an Object Relatonal Mapper. They don't do the same thing. If you want to use a data access library, Microsoft would recomend the Entity Framework. If you want to use an ORM. they would recomment EF.

Other similar question on here:

1. [Entity framework vs enterprise library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749398/entity-framework-vs-enterprise-library)
2. [General Questions about Entity Framework vs. Enterprise Library & a few others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356273/general-questions-about-entity-framework-vs-enterprise-library-a-few-others)